# How to set StructureMap 3 Lifecycle

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

In StructureMap 2 I had something like this:

```
For<ILogger>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<Logger>();
```

When using Structure Map 3 should I use the following?

```
For<ILogger>().LifecycleIs<HybridLifecycle>().Use<Logger>();
```

Then I tried to apply the same change to:

```
For<IDispatcher>().Transient().Use<Dispatcher>();
```

And I wasn't able to use:

```
For<IDispatcher>().LifecycleIs<Transient>().Use<Dispatcher>();
```

Why?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 8):

First you need to install the new `structuremap.web` package.

```
PM> install-package structuremap.web
```

Then add these namespaces to your class

```
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Web;
using StructureMap.Web.Pipeline;
```

Now you have access to the `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` as before.

Comment: Where can I get documentation about structuremap 3.0 news and other things like this package thanks.

Comment: You can find the official [StructureMap 3 documentation here](http://structuremap.github.io/).